# Foreword vs Preface in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

In the English language, *Foreword* and *Preface* are [different in meaning](http://www.bpsbooks.com/BPS-Books-blog/bid/21727/What-s-the-Difference-Between-a-Foreword-Preface-and-Introduction), and books frequently have both of those:

- *Foreword*: another author endorses the book,
- *Preface*: the author(s) tell how they came to write the book.

However, I am not sure how to make this distinction in German. The *Vorwort* seems to me to be more of a *preface* than a *foreword*.

How would these two different words be translated when they occur at the beginning of a book?

Comment: The distinction that you make between the English words "foreword" and "preface" is not correct. "Foreword" is not necessarily the work of another author. The two words are synonyms; the difference is that "preface" is a Latin loanword and "foreword" is a so-called "Saxonism", an artificial Englishing of a foreign word.

Comment: @fdb I added a link to an editor's explanation of the distinction who also cites the Chicago Manual of Style. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreword) agrees as well: "typically written by s/o else...". So while not strictly *necessarily*, the distinction generally holds in current professional use of English.

Comment: The linked article by the non-fiction editor does say “Different publishers and editors may define these elements of the front end of books differently”. I tend to have fairly similar expectations of a preface or foreword and assume they are worth reading before I get to the main text, whereas I am reluctant to read an introduction to a novel before the novel itself; with non-fiction I read an introduction beforehand too. In a novel a foreword is often and a preface sometimes a framing device and thus part of the work, while an introduction tends to be a commentary. Some statistics would help!

Comment: Vorwort and Einleitung perhaps?

Comment: @DevSolar Einleitung is *Introduction* and usually refers to the introductory part of the main body of the book -- not something “before“ the first chapter. So it's completely different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are called »Vorwort« in German. When a book has both a foreword and a preface, then the preface is often called

> Vorwort des Autors

Sometimes you also find

> Geleitwort

when it is a foreword.

Here is an example, the German translation of the 6<sup>th</sup> edition of *Design Patterns* by Gamma, Helm, Johnson and Vlissides. In this book we have at the beginning, before chapter 1 (which is »1 Einführung«):

- Vorwort des Übersetzers der 6ten Auflage
  <sup>(Foreword by the translator of the 6th edition)</sup>
- Vorwort des Übersetzers
  <sup>(Foreword by the translator)</sup>
- Vorwort
  <sup>(Preface)</sup>
- Geleitwort von Grady Booch
  <sup>(Foreword by Grady Booch)</sup>
- Leitfaden für den Leser
  <sup>(Reader's guide)</sup>
- 1 Einführung
  <sup>(1 Introduction)</sup>